# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (line 64, file "Instagram Automation") on a previously working code

Tags: google-sheets, instagram-api

I have been using this script someone wrote for my google spreadsheet to gather data, and it has been working really well for 10 days, then it suddenly gave me the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (line 64, file "Instagram Automation")
```

I altered the code slightly but it gave me instead the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined (line 30, file "Instagram Automation")
```

The bits of code here are:

```
    function fetch(url) {
  var ignoreError = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, ignoreError).getContentText();////
  ///var data = JSON.parse(source);
  return source;
}
```

(the /// is what I altered, and returned the source instead)

and

```
    function getFollowers() {
  return parseInt(fetch(instagram_base_url + followers)['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']);
}
```

I really hope someone can help!
:)

NOTE: I have re-copied all the code like I did the first time incase I accidentally did something that broke it but still got the same errors.

[Original github](https://gist.github.com/JulienDev/df5a3b66e899c224fa1b2dc90acfa2ae)
[How I came across the code](https://medium.com/@thomas.strosse/how-to-automatically-create-instagram-analytics-with-a-google-sheets-scripts-325ee5fa8e7e)

Comment: `console.log(source)` and look in the console to see what the response is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This person has solved the issue by using a cookie variable inside the script.

https://gist.github.com/JulienDev/df5a3b66e899c224fa1b2dc90acfa2ae#gistcomment-3531268

Follow his instructions and I can confirm it does work.

Comment: Thank youuuu I have been inputting everything manually like a mad man 

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same script and I'm getting the following response in the log (snippet):

```
[20-11-18 12:28:58:326 AEDT] Logging output too large. Truncating output. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
                  Page Not Found &bull; Instagram
                </title>

        
        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">
```

I've tested the fetch URL structure in a browser tab and I am getting a JSON so I'm confused as to why the response is syaing Page Not Found.

The only other hint I can see is in the class not-logged-in

Comment: I did another test to and I got the Response Code 429

'[20-11-18 12:42:32:287 AEDT] 429'

Which means "Too Many Requests" so this probably means Google Scripts have been blocked or blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

This is because, during the last day, Instagram has updated the policy of working with cookies. If you log in as a registered user, you will probably get the correct result with the required JSON.

But if your IP is compromised, for example in the Incognito tab you will be redirected to the login page. This corresponds to the HTML code that you have attached.

In the developer tools, you will see 302 redirections to the login page. If you can break through to a tag search page, for example, you will find that new data is not loaded when you scroll.

I think there will be more discussions on this issue soon.